# Is there a benefit to clearing snow in rimworld?

Tags: rimworld

Is there a benefit to clearing snow during winter in RimWorld?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Moving over snow is slower. Clearing it will allow your colonists to travel more quickly.

Whether it's worth actually clearing it during winter if the path's just going to get snowed on again depends on your climate and how often that path needs to be used.

Personally, I try to keep a clear path between all my buildings unless the weather reaches coldsnap levels and colonists remain indoors anyway.